# OpenMP device offload reduction to existing device memory location

Tags: openmp

How do I tell OpenMP device offload to use an existing location in device memory for a reduction? I want to avoid data movement to/from device. Results will only be accessed on the device.

Here's my code

```cpp
void reduce(const double *mi, const double *xi, const double *yi,                                                                                
    double *mo, double *xo, double *yo, long n)
{
    #pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for reduction(+: mo[0],xo[0],yo[0]) is_device_ptr(mi,xi,yi,mo,xo,yo)
    for (long i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {   
        mo[0] += mi[i];
        xo[0] += mi[i]*xi[i];
        yo[0] += mi[i]*yi[i];
    }   

    #pragma omp target is_device_ptr(mo,xo,yo)
    {   
    xo[0] /= mo[0];
    yo[0] /= mo[0];
    }   
}
```

with this code and clang++ 15 targeting nvidia ptx, I'm getting the error:

```
test.cpp:6:109: error: reduction variable cannot be in a is_device_ptr clause in '#pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for' directive
    #pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for reduction(+: mo[0],xo[0],yo[0]) is_device_ptr(mi,xi,yi,mo,xo,yo)
                                                                                                            ^
test.cpp:6:67: note: defined as reduction
    #pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for reduction(+: mo[0],xo[0],yo[0]) is_device_ptr(mi,xi,yi,mo,xo,yo)
                                                                  ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do this all on the device. A couple of key pieces of info were required:

1. the `map` clause's map-type is used to optimize the copies to/from the device and disable unnecessary copies. The `alloc` map-type disables both copies to and from the device.
2. variables have only one instance in the device. `map` clauses for variables already mapped by an enclosing `target data` or `target enter data` by default do not result in copies to/from the device.

With that the solution is as follows:

```cpp
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
void reduce(const double *mi, const double *xi, const double *yi,
    double *mo, double *xo, double *yo, long n)
{
    double m, x, y;
    #pragma omp target enter data map(alloc: m,x,y)

    #pragma omp target map(alloc: m,x,y)
    {   
    m = 0.; 
    x = 0.; 
    y = 0.; 
    }   

    #pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for reduction(+: m,x,y), \
        is_device_ptr(mi,xi,yi), map(alloc: m,x,y)
    for (long i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {   
        m += mi[i];
        x += mi[i]*xi[i];
        y += mi[i]*yi[i];
    }   

    #pragma omp target is_device_ptr(mo,xo,yo), map(alloc: m,x,y)
    {   
    mo[0] = m;
    xo[0] = x/m;
    yo[0] = y/m;
    }   

    #pragma omp target exit data map(release: m,x,y)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use array subscripts in `reduction` clause.  That's non-conforming code.  Please try something along these lines:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    double sum = 0;

    #pragma omp target data map(tofrom:sum)
    {
        for (int t = 0; t < 10; t++) {
            #pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for map(tofrom:sum) reduction(+:sum)
            for (int j = 0; j < 10000; j++) {
                sum += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("sum=%lf\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

With the the `target data` construct you can allocate a buffer for the reduction variable on the GPU.  The `target` construct's `reduction` clause will then reduce the value into that buffered variable and will only transfer the variable back from the GPU at the closing curly brace of the `target data` construct.

Comment: Thanks for this. It's not really solving my problem though. I have data on the GPU to reduce, the the result of the reduction is used in subsequent calculation on the GPU. I will only access the reduction result on the GPU, and need to prevent OpenMP from moving the single value to the CPU and then back to the GPU. Your suggestion has the `map(tofrom:sum)` which brings the result of the reduction back to the CPU. Then I'll have to move the value back to the GPU to use it. I am trying to avoid these unneeded data movement since it's negatively impacting the performance of the code.

Comment: My example tries to mimic what you are trying to accomplish.  The `sum` variable exists on the GPU throughout the 10 kernel executions of the `for` loop on `t`.  If you do not want to bring sum back from the GPU, then either replace `tofrom` with `to`, or even just just `map(alloc:sum)` to even save the initial copy of `sum` from host to GPU. I cannot save you from refactoring the code to use variables for `reduction` instead of array slices.

Comment: OK, thanks for the pointers. Your comments nudged me in the right direction and I found the right places in the documentation to make clear what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

**BEWARE** this is a tentative, unverified answer, since I don't have the target, and [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org) doesn.t seem to have a gcc which has offload enabled. Hence **this is untested**.

However, you can clearly try this for yourself!

I suggest splitting the directives, and adding explicit scalar locals for the reduction.

So your code would look something like this

```
void reduce(const double *mi, const double *xi, const double *yi,                                                                                
    double *mo, double *xo, double *yo, long n)
{
    #pragma omp target is_device_ptr(mi,xi,yi,mo,xo,yo)
    {
        double mTotal = 0.0;
        double xTotal = 0.0;
        double yTotal = 0.0;

        #pragma omp teams distribute parallel for reduction(+: mTotal, xTotal, yTotal) 
        for (long i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {   
            mTotal += mi[i];
            xTotal += mi[i]*xi[i];
            yTotal += mi[i]*yi[i];
        }   
   
        mo[0] = mTotal; 
        xo[0] = xTotal/mTotal;
        yo[0] = yTotal/mTotal;
    }   
}
```

That compiles OK for the host, but, as above, **YOUR MILEAGE MAY VARY**

Comment: OK, thanks, but this doesn't compile. `error: target construct with nested teams region contains statements outside of the teams construct` points to the definition of mTotal.  I've tried various permutations like this and have struck out. One aspect I'm trying to get my head around is that the default mapping for reductions is tofrom which would potentially need to be modified to prevent moving these values.